# How can draw a line using the x and y coordinates of two points?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to draw a line using the x and y coordinates of two 2-dimensional points. I tried the turtle graphics, but it works using degrees.

Comment: use matplotlib and .plot method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of pygame depending on what you are doing it for as it allows a similar:

```
line(Surface, color, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), width)
```

For Example, when the environment has been set up:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,0,255), (20,20), (70,80), 2)
```

can draw:

[image: Test line]

Comment: i have problem whit "screen" what is it ?

Answer (score 13):

Depending of your needs for plotting you can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

> I tried the turtle graphics, but it works using degrees.

Your premise doesn't hold -- turtle can do it, no degrees needed:

```
import turtle

point1 = (50, 100)
point2 = (150, 200)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(point1)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.goto(point2)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are already using `turtle` you can use a `Tkinter` canva :

```
import tkinter
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10, 20, 30, 40
window = tkinter.Tk()
canva = tkinter.Canvas(window)
line = canva.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
canva.pack()
```

Comment: this code rub but don't show anything for me . i use pycharm

Comment: It doesn't show anything for me either but I don't use PyCharm. How did we end up with Python 2 code when OP specified [python-3.x]?  Global replace 'Tkinter' with 'tkinter' and add a last line that says `window.mainloop()` and it should run for you under generic Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, you can also use the [ImageDraw module of Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html) (Python Image Library / PIL fork). That way you don't need a window and you can save the drawn image into a file instead.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line((0, 0) + im.size, fill=128)
draw.line((0, im.size[1], im.size[0], 0), fill=128)

im.save('test.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the angle from the 4 points using the following formula

```
angle = arctan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
```

Just a warning, depending on the math library you use, this will probably output in radians.  However you can convert radians to degrees using the following formula.

```
deg = rad * (180/pi)
```